# Does a GPU which supports CUDA also support OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I know CUDA is for only Nvidia GPUs. If the specifications for a Nvidia graphics card states that CUDA is supported, can we conclude that it also supports OpenCL? Can there be support/compatibility problems with different OpenCL versions? i.e. OpenCL 1.0 or 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that in version 4.1 of the [OpenCL Programming Guide (PDF)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/OpenCL/doc/OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) Nvidia explicitly speaks about CUDA-Enabled GPUs (Especially in Appendix A), I think we can safely assume that those cards supporting CUDA also support OpenCL. Even more so since OpenCL on Nvidia hardware still makes use of the CUDA architecture.

Appendix C of the same document lists the support of various extensions given a specific compute capability.

Comment: Yes, all the OpenCL stuff and the CUDA stuff are bundled into the same NVIDIA driver, downloadable at nvidia.com/drivers

Answer (score 2):

According to Nvidia's OpenCL page (http://developer.nvidia.com/opencl), all CUDA devices support OpenCL. As far as OpenCL versioning, that page indicates that you just need to make sure you have the right driver version.